# Input data from database and process it

Tags: java, text-mining

as shown in title, i have a code that can tokenize, stopping, and stemming for text mining.. but the code can only process the word i give in "String result" line.. how can i do if i want to input the data i have in database? and then the result is saved in other database..

```
class TokenizeStopStem
{
private  Set<String> stop_word_set;

public TokenizeStopStem(){

    BufferedReader fileStream = null;
    try {
        stop_word_set = new HashSet<String>();
        String path = "E:\\stopwords.txt";
        File file = new File(path);
        fileStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String kata;
        while ( ( kata = fileStream.readLine() ) != null)
            stop_word_set.add(kata);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TokenizeStopStem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String result = tokenizeStopStem("Coba kalo yang ini mau bermain gimana jadinya kegantengan");
    System.out.println(result);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TokenizeStopStem();

}


private  String tokenizeStopStem(String input) {

    TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(
            Version.LUCENE_36, new StringReader(input));
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenStream, stop_word_set);
    tokenStream = new IndonesianStemFilter(tokenStream);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
    CharTermAttribute charTermAttr = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    try{
        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append(charTermAttr.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Fetch data from DB table using JDBC and pass data as String to your method. Write tokenizeStopStem String to db using JDBC again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your "Coba kalo" string with a method that returns a string called `loadRawData()`.  `loadRawData` would probably look something like this:

```
private String loadRawData(String id) throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = getSourceConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select data from table where id='" + id + "'";

    String rawData = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            rawData = rs.getString("data");
        }
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
    return rawData;
}
```

It calls `getSourceConnection()` which creates a Connection instance pointing to the database where you will retrieve your data.  [See here for how to establish a connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).  The "id" passed in is presumably a way to uniquely identify your record, and in fact the data returned if found, will be the data found in column "data".  If there is no error, but no record is found, it will return null, so you should prepare for that possibility.

You should surround the call with a try ... catch, so you can deal with unexpected problems should they arise.

If everything goes well, and you have your result, you should pass that result to a method called `saveTokenData` passing the string.  Unfortunately, I cannot know how you wish to save this information, so I cannot enter details, however you'll see that the code is very similar to the code above, with the exception that you would call `getDestinationConnection()` instead of `getSourceConnection()` and you would be calling `executeUpdate` with an update query rather than `executeQuery`.

This will do the trick, however, you should consider using threads to do this.  This will greatly improve the efficiency of this program, however, it will also considerably complicate it as well.  My advice is to first get it running, and afterwards you can attempt to use threads.

Hope that helps!

[Reference for retrieving data from a database using JDBC.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Comment: sory neil, i'm a noob in java.. can u be more spesific, where i need to put that code? i already trying 2 hours (since you answered this) but cannot find the right place to put the code you give..

Comment: @YoasLiong You should put it in the same place as `tokenizeStopStem` to start.  Maybe later you should put persistence methods like `loadRawData` and `saveTokenData` in its own class.

Comment: can help me again? its says "missing return statement". and btw, which part do i need to read for my problem? because i cannot see a part contain saveTokenData  and other things you said before.

Comment: @YoasLiong It should return `rawData`.  I didn't write saveTokenData.  That is left as an exercise for you to do.